# ios phonegap disallow overscroll not working properly

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently developing an application using phonegap,jquery mobile for multiple platforms.
I have searched a lot to disable the overscroll effect in phonegap.
As per my search this can be achieved by setting the preferences in confix.xml

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Also i have used the javascript code for allowing the body scroll but this is not working properly.
Below is the code that i used to allow the body scroll.

```
.scrollable {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.scrollable * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){ 
     if(!$(e.target).hasClass("scrollable")) {
       e.preventDefault();
     }
     else
     {
         console.log("Scrollable");
     }
 });
```

Is there any way to solve this issue out

Comment: @Ross I am using 2.8.1

Comment: Are you by any chance using the Phonegap build service?

Comment: Making change to the CDViewController is a separate thing. Its basically a hack not a logic. I need to understand the probable solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phonegap, I found I had to actually fully uninstall the app and re-install it for the change in config.xml to take effect and stop the overscrolling.