# PhoneGap iOS prevent overscroll

Tags: uiwebview, cordova

> PhoneGap version: 2.9
>
> Test device: 3gs with iOS 6.1.3
>
> I'm using the PhoneGap build service provided by Adobe

I want to prevent the whole app from overscrolling. I've read the related questions and added the following to my `config.xml`

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

which has no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this same question that was asked yesterday - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530019/ios-phonegap-disallow-overscroll-not-working-properly/17550558#17550558 - I believe there is an error in the CDVViewController.m file.  I don't know if you can edit this as you are using the PhoneGap build service.

Comment: @Ross Just found the solution. See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found it: it's `webviewbounce` not `UIWebViewBounce`

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

PhoneGap Build will translate this to `DisallowOverscroll`.

See http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/2_7_0_webview_bounce_bug for discussion.

Comment: Hmm, it must be different for PhoneGap build.  In the CDVViewController.m file it shows `NSNumber* bouncePreference = [self.settings objectForKey:@"UIWebViewBounce"];` and `NSNumber* disallowOverscroll = [self.settings objectForKey:@"DisallowOverscroll"];` - This CDVViewController.m checks the values from config.xml and configures the webView to allow/disallow the overscroll.  Line 323 of this file looks for `UIWebViewBounce`

Comment: As far as I understood, the PhoneGap build service doesn't support all preferences. So neither `DisallowOverscroll` nor `UIWebViewBounce` ended up in the actual config.xml which got bundled. It's now working on my 3gs with `webviewbounce`.

Answer (score 2):

I am using PhoneGap version 3.0.0

I had to do two things to get this working:

Firstly:
I had this set in my index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

Needed to change this to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

When setting device height, my 100% heights were taking into consideration the status bar.

I then also had to add this line into my config.xml:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Hope this helps,

Ian

Comment: Thanks This one worked for me since I'm using Phonegap version 3.0+. But this worked me without making any changes in the stuff <meta name="viewport"..../>