# Disable IOS Safari Elastic Scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios7, mobile-safari

I am writing a web app in HTML and JavaScript for use on an iPhone. What I would like to achieve is preventing the app from elastic scrolling (scrolling past the pages extents and bouncing back). However, I need some of the longer elements of my app to be able to be scrolled (the app has a long canvas).

I have tried many answers to this found elsewhere on the internet, however, all of those solutions either used JQuery, disabled scrolling altogether, used Phonegap or just plain didn't work on IOS 7. How can I do this?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16898264/112731

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable rubber band in iOS web apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357844/how-to-disable-rubber-band-in-ios-web-apps)

Comment: The solution given on that question no longer works. You experience jittering at the upper and lower limits.

Answer (score 22):

There is a way to achieve this without jQuery:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But this is not a proper solution. It's better to wrap your content in some div, and use css property on it:

```
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/) is the example

**Edit:**

This will only prevent overscroll in webview, not in app. So you need to disable this feature in app config.
If you use **phonegap**:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

More description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651215/how-to-disable-bouncing-in-html5-fullscreen-iphone-app)

If you don't use **phonegap**, you can use [this](http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/stop-the-bouncy-uiwebviews/).

Comment: This stops you scrolling at all. I want to be able to scroll, but I don't want the page to go past its extremities.

Comment: So, allow scrolling, but not do this [link](http://cdn.ismashphone.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/iOSRubber.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550704/phonegap-ios-prevent-overscroll might be helpful

Comment: That's only for those who use PhoneGap

Comment: @user2376055 If you don't use phonegap, you can use http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/stop-the-bouncy-uiwebviews/

Comment: that last link was a real winner!

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

One of the other solutions here was insufficient in my case. It prohibits all scrolling. It is possible to build a solution here that prevents elastic scrolling in iOS, but that still allows scrolling on children. I this took the above solution and added a check that bubbles up the DOM to determine which scrollable element "owns" the scroll event, and if it's the root element of the page, I drop it:

```
function overflowIsHidden(node) {
  var style = getComputedStyle(node);
  return style.overflow === 'hidden' || style.overflowX === 'hidden' || style.overflowY === 'hidden';
}

function findNearestScrollableParent(firstNode) {
  var node = firstNode;
  var scrollable = null;
  while(!scrollable && node) {
    if (node.scrollWidth > node.clientWidth || node.scrollHeight > node.clientHeight) {
      if (!overflowIsHidden(node)) {
        scrollable = node;
      }
    }
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return scrollable;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
      var owner = findNearestScrollableParent(event.target);
      if (!owner || owner === document.documentElement || owner === document.body) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });

}, false);
```

At this point, the body is no longer scrollable or elastically scrollable in iOS, but children elements are. You can then add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to those children so they are elastic but the document won't be. This will actually capture all scroll events even as you scroll to the bottom of the children, so the window's scroll position won't ever change erroneously. Alternatively you may also consider:

```
['resize', 'orientationchange', 'scroll'].forEach(function(event) {
  window.addEventListener(event, function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
});
```

which in addition to the first code block I shared, should really throw an axe at document scrolling in iOS altogether.

Answer (score 1):

So when you have scroll content in body & want to disable elastic scroll 
use:

```
let scrollToTop = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scrollToTop < 0) {
   // do something here
}
```

Because elastic scroll will always have negative value

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer by @umidbek this is how it worked for me

```
     document.getElementById('content-sections').
         addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
         });
```